# How to create a custom video: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')

Tags: javascript, css

I watching a video on how to create a custom video player in Atom. I have got to step to creating the different const but getting a error message take saying that line 2 of `const video = player.querySelector('.player-video');`

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')**

When the user clicks on the play video button, I want the user to watch the video:

I have my class name with: `<video controls class="player-video" height="369px" width="610px" class="video" id="video" preload="metadata" poster="assets/img/photo.jpg">`

```js
const player = document.querySelector('.player');
const video = player.querySelector('.player-video');
const progress = player.querySelector('.progress');
const progressFilled = player.querySelector('.filled-progress');
const toggle = player.querySelector('.toggle-play');
const skippers = player.querySelectorAll('[data-skip]');
const ranges = player.querySelectorAll('.player-slider');

function togglePlay() {
  const playState = video.paused ? 'play' : 'paused';
 }

function updateButton() {
  const togglePlayBtn = document.querySelector('.toggle-play');

  if(this.pause) {
    togglePlayBtn.innerHTML + `<svg class="" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><title>play</title><path d="M3 2l10 6-10 6z"></path></svg>`;
  } else {
    togglePauseBtn.innerHTML + `<svg class="" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><title>pause</title><path d="M3 2l10 6-10 6z"></path></svg>`
  }
}

video.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
video.addEventListener('play', updateButton);
video.addEventListener('pause', updateButton);
video.addEventListener('timeupdated', progressUpdate);

toggle.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
skippers.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', skip));
ranges.forEach(range => range.addEventListener('change', rangeUpdate));
range.forEach(range => range.addEventListener('mousemove', rangeUpdate));

let mousemove = false;

progress.addEventListener('click', scrub);
progress.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => mousedown && scrub(e));
progress.addEventListener('mousedown', () => mousedown = true);
progress.addEventListener('mouseup', () => mousedown = false);
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="video player">
            <video controls class="player-video" height="369px" width="610px" class="video" id="video" preload="metadata" poster="assets/img/photo.jpg">
                <source src="/assets/video/bjp__video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="/assets/video/bjp__video.webm" type="video/webm">
            </video>

            <div class="name">
                <img draggable alt="name" src="assets/img/bjp_title.png">
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="info__hero__content">
              <p>I help  <span><b>people with disabilities</b></span> and <span><b>entrepreneurs</b></span>  to find there hide abilities and resources for there businesses.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="play__btn">
     <button class="player-btn toggle-play" title="Toggle Play" id="play">
          <svg class="" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><title>play</title><path d="M3 2l10 6-10 6z"></path></svg>
     </button>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: querySelector() returns null if no element is found matching the input. So when you call for document.querySelector('.player') there is not element that matches the .player selector

Comment: `const progress = player.querySelector('.progress');` is null theres no element in the html with this class

Comment: I have a element in my html call ` <video controls class="player-video" ` So so trying to figure out why not finding the class name of the element

Comment: @Woohaik the error is stating that the player is null, and thus doesnt have the property querySelector.

Comment: this error is coming from the first line of code where you set player equal to document.querySelector('.player'). so there is no element with the 'player' class

Comment: @about14sheep But Im getting the element from player, not null. Im getting this in the console for console.log(player):  `<div class="video player">`

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you `.querySelector` cannot be called on the object `player`, because player is `null` and not an object. This means the node you tried to store a reference to in the `player` variable was not found in your document at the time. Are you sure that the element is present at the time of storing the reference, or is it perhaps rendered asynchronously by any chance?

/e: Referring to your comments above: the value printed to console.log is evaluated later on (Chrome used to display hints for that because it is somewhat misleading). You can try to console.log any attribute or other form of your variable. For objects you could `JSON.stringify()`, for nodes that could be `.innerHTML` of the parent container for example.

Comment: Where will the object of JSON.stringify() go thank for your reply.

Comment: JSON.stringify-ing a node reference will only print `{}`. If you want to check what elements are in the DOM at the time of your `console.log` call, you could do `document.body.innerHTML`. This is not a fix to your problem, though - it just helps finding the cause.

Comment: `console.log(document.body.innerHTML). this the right way to do it

Comment: I have tried but nothing is happen with the console an done console.log()